# Ocultar en bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Estoy intentando ocultar un texto de la siguiente manera

```
<ul class="col-6 col-lg-4">
    <li>
       <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <div class="contenedor-eleccion ">
         <h4>Aplicaciones para la nube</h4>
         <p class="hidden-md-down">Para empresa que requiera ampliar sus plataformas de gestión.</p>
       </div>
    </li>
```

Pero la clase hidden-md-down no funciona. En la documentación de bootstrap 4 pone que se realiza de esta manera. 
[Responsive utilities - bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

Comment: Buenas Borja, ¿Tienes en la pantalla la resolución confirmada que actúa con las medidas a las que afecta esa clase?

Comment: La clase se ocultará cuando la pantalla sea md o menor, https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#test-cases ahí tienes los test que te indicarán en verde si cumple

Comment: Yo usaría la clase `.hidden-xs-up` o `.hidden-xl-up` y así ya te lo oculta en todas las resoluciones.

Comment: Me he fijado que en la version de bottstrap de github en el css han quitado las clases hidden, supongo que estaran toqueteando algo

Comment: "_Pero la clase hidden-md-down no funciona_". ¿Cómo no funciona? ¿Se oculta siempre? ¿Se muestra siempre? ¿No se oculta en las resoluciones que debería ocultarse?

Comment: yo tambien quiero hacer lo mismo y esa clase hidden-md-down ya no funciona estuve buscando en la documentacion de bootstrap pero no encuentro alguna clase que haga lo mismo

Answer (score 4):

Las clases hidden-* fueron eliminadas en la version 4 de bootstrap, ahora tienes que utilizar "d-none d-lg-block" para ocultar en todos los tamaños menos en el largo.

Comment: Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad. por favor expandela. mira [answer]

Comment: Considero que esta es la respuesta correcta, pero agrega mas detalle, una explicación más amplia y también puedes incluir este [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23475) de GitHub que explica las equivalencias de `hidden-*` a `d-*-*` por si alguien mas tiene la duda y llega hasta aquí en busca de la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de `hidden-md-down` funcionando.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>Este div se muestra.</div>
<div class="hidden-md-down">Este div no.</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Es posible que te falte alguna de las librerias necesarias (jQuery y Tether), o que la resolución de la pantalla en la que estás probando tu código sea superior a la de la clase, en este caso menor que 992px.

Answer (score 1):

¿Con que versión de bootstrap estas trabajando? Pues la versión actual de Bootstrap es 4.3...

Según su documentación esta es una forma para ocultar elementos, pero nada mas lo oculta y ocupa un espacio.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="visible">Aqui esta</div>
<div class="invisible">Aqui no esta.</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Visibilidad](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/visibility/)

Ahora si quieres ocultar algo según la dimesión de la pantalla...
Existe otras clases.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <div class="d-none">Esta clase lo oculta para todo</div>
    
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block">Esta clase lo oculta para pantallas extra-pequeñas
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-none d-md-block">Esta clase lo oculta para pantallas pequeñas
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block">Esta clase lo oculta para pantallas medianas
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-none d-xl-none">Esta clase lo oculta para pantallas grandes
    </div>

    <div class=" d-xl-none">Esta clase lo oculta para pantallas extra-grandes
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Puedes instruirte mejor en la documentación de Bootstrap. Espero haberte ayudado.
[Ocultar elementos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

Te recomiendo ver los ejemplos en pantalla completa, para que visualices mejor.

Answer (score 0):

la clase en `.hidden` se elimino en la version 4 ahorra se utiliza la clase `.d-none`

```
<div class="d-none">no soy visible</div>
```

segun la documentación que hay en el siguiente link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p class='errorposicion_x text-center alert alert-danger hidden'>este se muestra</p>
<p class='errorposicion_x text-center alert alert-danger d-none'>este no se muestra</p>
<p class='errorposicion_x text-center alert alert-danger hidden'> y este si se muestra</p>
```